# Android path not following coordinates in relative view

Tags: android

I have a custom path which I got the coordinates from Adobe Illustrator, it's relative to a 600x600 rectangle. When I try to draw that path on Android for my Custom View, it doesn't draw at the correct size and correct location within my view. Does the density affect these coordinates? I know the canvas origin is at 0,0 for the onDraw method of my custom view but I even did the following:

```
Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(600, 600, Config.ARG_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
canvas.drawPath(myCustomPath);
```

When I check my result Bitmap, the path isn't close to where it's suppose to be. I can't figure out why it isn't working.

Thanks

I've added some images on what I get:

First this is where the original path should be:
[image: Original Path]

This is what I see on my Android canvas:
[image: Path on Android]

As you can see, the path on the actual image isn't the same size as the one you see in Illustrator. Could this be due to my screen size on the device?

Comment: Could you post some images of the expected and the actual output? Also, do you know the origin is in the upper-left corner, with the y-coordinate increasing downward?

Comment: There you go @MikeM.added some images

Comment: It appears the difference in densities is causing the size disparity. That wouldn't cause the difference in relative positions as seen in the first set of images you had up, though.

Comment: Yeah relative positions is probably due to the translation i'm doing on the Rect not sure how i can fix the size disparity though.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out what my Problem was, I just wasn't scaling my Path correctly and I wasn't translating correctly to the Path's relative parent view and it's position on the Canvas.